# Extentreports suddenly not generating Dashboard with certain scenario outline with a tag

Tags: specflow, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Currently I have extentreport implemented in my SpecFlow/Selenium solution. It is still generating the html file for me and showing me results per test case, but suddenly it stopped generating the Dashboard. It shows the Dashboard in the left menu, but now the graphs and charts are missing and the page turns out white.

Now I have seen what the problem is, it seems to be one of my scenario outline examples contains a tag for checking an attribute. Its a simple bold tag. How would I escape this for extent reports?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [repro], otherwise we do not have enough information to provide an answer.